# Database connection issue - App unable to recover

Tags: postgresql, jakarta-ee, jboss7.x

I have a Java EE Web App running on JBoss AS 7.2 connecting to a Postgresql 9.4 database (hosted on RDS).

The App is quite large and does a mixture of web page serving, API calls and Scheduled Tasks

More and more frequently I am having to reboot the application server as the whole app has ground to a halt, checking DB stats I can see the number of connections has gone through the roof along with database CPU

[image]

(big spike as app stops responding, soon as I restart Jboss it drops back)

The database logs show that the connection to the client has been lost:

```
LOG: could not send data to client: Broken pipe
FATAL: connection to client lost
```

The jboss logs start filling up as transactions time-out...

```
Caused by: javax.transaction.RollbackException: ARJUNA016063: The transaction is not active!
```

The only way to fix is to restart JBoss and the number of connections goes back to normal.

My DB datasource configuration looks like this..

```
<datasource jta="false" jndi-name="java:/appWebDatasource" pool-name="jdbc/appWebDatasource" enabled="true" use-java-context="true" use-ccm="false">
                    <connection-url>jdbc:postgresql://${web.db.url}/MyApp</connection-url>
                    <driver>postgresql</driver>
                    <security>
                        <user-name>jboss</user-name>
                        <password>******</password>
                    </security>
                    <validation>
                        <check-valid-connection-sql>select 1</check-valid-connection-sql>
                        <validate-on-match>false</validate-on-match>
                        <background-validation>true</background-validation>
                    </validation>
                    <statement>
                        <share-prepared-statements>false</share-prepared-statements>
                    </statement>
                </datasource>
```

I have been checking the `pg_stat_activity` table as soon as the issue occurs and there are no `idle in transaction` connections, they are all either idle or active

So my question is, how to configure JBoss or Postgresql in a way to stop this increase in number of connections that crashes the app??

Answer (score 0):

You can have a cap on the max number of connections by declaring the max pool size you want to allow with this paramater `<max-pool-size>`

You have to consider your application and choose an appropriate size to set in `<max-pool-size>`

Comment: this doesn't seem to work, number of connections still rises beyond the max-pool-size number

Answer (score 0):

As you need to use the validation checker mechanism also along with parameter   already mentioned by DaveB in data source configuration, given in the [doc](https://developer.jboss.org/wiki/ConnectionValidationInJBossAS7).

Comment: thanks, I am testing with updated data source config, will see how it goes